# ERROR Call to a member function

Tags: php

Tengo esta function

```
 public function insertUserAssignment($objeto)
{
    $curp = $this->realescapestring($objeto->getCurp());
    $idAreaAcademica = $this->realescapestring($objeto->getidAreaAcademica());
    $idAsignaturas = $this->realescapestring($objeto->getidAsignaturas());
    $idTema = $this->realescapestring($objeto->getidTema());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO alumno_asignacion (";
    $sql .= "curp,idAreaAcademica,idAsignaturas,idTema";
    $sql .= ") VALUES (";
    $sql .= "'" . $curp . "',";
    $sql .= "'" . $idAreaAcademica . "',";
    $sql .= "'" . $idAsignaturas . "',";
    $sql .= "'" . $idTema . "',";
    $sql .= ")";
    $this->query = $sql;
    $resultado = $this->execute_single_query_assignament();
}
```

y la pruebo con este test  drive

```
$objeto=['ASDG60810MCHXDRA2',1,1,1];

 include("class_user_assignment_dal.php");
 $rs= new UserAssignmentDal();
 $lista=$rs->insertUserAssignment($objeto = null);
 print "<pre>";
 print_r($lista);
  print "</pre>";
```

me sale el siguiente error 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCurp() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\class_user_assignment_dal.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrive_eval.php(62): UserAssignmentDal->insertUserAssignment(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\class_user_assignment_dal.php on line 14

la linea 14 es esta linea de mi funcion

$curp = $this->realescapestring($objeto->getCurp());

alguien sabe porque me sale ese error?

Comment: `$objeto` es nulo en ese contexto. Puedes depurarlo haciendo `var_dump($objeto);` para verificarlo. Tampoco muestras el contexto de esa línea 14, por lo que es complicado ayudarte. ¿Cómo se crea `$objeto`?

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
$lista=$rs->insertUserAssignment($objeto = null);
```

Estas igualando la variable `$objeto` a null antes de llamar a la funcion.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```
$lista=$rs->insertUserAssignment($objeto);
```

Comment: me sigue marcando el mismo error en la linea 14   $curp = $this->realescapestring($objeto->getCurp());

Comment: Seguro que es el mismo error? o es otro?  Estas intentando llamar a la funcion `getCurp()` y le estas pasando un array.  Creo que te falta un paso.  `$objeto` deberia de ser un objeto y no un array.

Comment: si es el mismo error